# Need a single app solution for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, iphone

I am sure it is a silly question to ask. But i need help from expert. I want to build a web based application which will be hosted with `database(Mysql)` in a server and can insert,update,view etc operation from Desktop using internet. At the same time i like to build app for both `android` and `iPhone` so that some of the functionality (`insert,update`etc) can be done from `android` device and `iPhone`. `User Interface` and `Database` is same for three platforms. so my question is

What is the best way to build this application (`desktop,android and iPhone`) so that i can use same user interface for android and iPhone? Need to check invalid input for all three platforms.need to login for permitted user.

Expert advice will help me to go ahead. I am sorry to ask this kind of very basic question.

Comment: You yourself said it. A web app. Let the sql manage the database. All you need is a small interface that shows the webpage that you have hosted in both android and iphone. :) Manage insert, update everything in server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to build an HTML5 web site that is viewed the same way in android an IOs devices and of course in the Desktop application. If you want to make interactions with the SQL then you must have internet connection.

If you want to build application and not a website there is this commonly known cross platform application builder(http://phonegap.com/) that lets you write HTML5 code and build it as an application in every device. Basically what it does is port a web site as an application. It also supports some common javascript calls for interacting with the phone's capabilities(like camera etc) but in your case this is not needed.

More details can be found on the website I posted

Comment: Thank you very much.It is really helpful.It is website for desktop and application for android and iPhone user to access some functionality from app. Please give me the website link where you post details.Thank you. Kabir